# Перезаписать поле в файле

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

У меня есть json файлы. я их собираю, пробегаю по всем, внутри файлов есть поле: old_text и text. И мне нужно если text - пустое, заполнить его из old_text. Я записывал данные в  другой файл. Но перезаписью поля одного файла не занимался...Код приведу ниже.

```
def process!
      paths = `ls ../admin/db/fs/item/json/product/*.json`.split("\n")
      paths.each do |path|
        file = File.read path
        hash_description = JSON.parse(file)
        if hash_description['text'] && hash_description['text'].empty?
          if hash_description['old_text'] && !hash_description['old_text'].empty? 

            File.write path, hash_description.to_json # Вот тут,к сожал. не знаю что писать
          end
        end
        print 'hash_description: '.red; puts hash_description
      end

    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, Вы уже решили вопрос, не хватает пары строк всего. Вы преобразовываете Json в хэш, и можете заменить поле так:

```
hash_description['text'] = hash_description['old_text']
```

А затем уже перезаписать Ваши все json файлы

```
File.write path, hash_description.to_json
```

Вот этой строчкой

Comment: ага, работает, спасибо